# Magento 1.7 collection and joinField

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a custom table `starmall_config_shop` with columns `id` and `name`.

I added custom attribute `shop_id` to product table.

I want to get the `name` from `starmall_config_shop`

When I do

```
$rs = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('shop_id');

$rs->joinField('shop_name','starmall_config/shop','name','id=shop_id'
    ,NULL,'left');
```

I get the error

`Unknown column 'at_shop_id.value' in 'on clause'`

`$rs->printlogquery(true)` gives:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_shop_name`.`name` AS `shop_name` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `starmall_config_shop` AS `at_shop_name` ON (at_shop_name.`id`=at_shop_id.value)
```

I see that I'm probably missing a join to the attributes table.

Where does `at_shop_id.value` come from?
How can I get the `name` column in the query?

===================

Current working solution is to use:

`->addAttributeToSelect('shop_id', 'left')`   ---> works

`->addAttributeToSelect('shop_id')`   ---> does not work

Comment: At a glance, your code seems OK to me, you are clearing attempting to join the shop_id attribute, but it isn't in your sql. If anything I'd guess you have flat catalog enabled and require a reindex, or your caches clearing.

Comment: Just checked but in configuration flat catalog is not enabled. For development I have disabled caching. To be sure deleted cache folder, but query still fails. Yes it's not in the sql, guess I need to find out how to get the custom product attribute `shop_id` into the query.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but are you sure you deleted the right cache directory. My number one issue when working with Magento is I forget to make the var directory writable and it creates the cache in /tmp/.

Comment: To check I deleted the complete /var folder. It was auto recreated with subfolders and files in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the system.log I see:

> Recoverable Error: Object of class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection could not be converted to string

I searched and found there is a second parameter:

```
addAttributeToSelect($attribute, $joinType=false)
```

It works when I now use:

```
addAttributeToSelect('shop_id', 'left');
```

The generated query is then:

```
SELECT e.*, at_shop_id.value AS shop_id, at_shop_name.name AS shop_name
FROM catalog_product_entity AS e
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int 
    AS at_shop_id 
   ON (at_shop_id.entity_id = e.entity_id) 
  AND (at_shop_id.attribute_id = 973) 
  AND (at_shop_id.store_id = 0)
LEFT JOIN starmall_config_shop 
    AS at_shop_name 
   ON (at_shop_name.id=at_shop_id.value)
```

But I still don't know why??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
'id=shop_id'.
```

Try to use

```
"entity_id=shop_id"
```

if shop_id it's a field from table at_shop_name.

Comment: I think the left side in `id=shop_id` is correct, because the generated join is `LEFT JOIN starmall_config_shop AS at_shop_name ON (at_shop_name.id=at_shop_id.value)` where `at_shop_name.id` is the `PK` from `starmall_config_shop` table.